# Why is the voltage dropping when using pwm output pin of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

A resistor is connected to one of the pwm output of Arduino. When I add a diode(or a capacitor) in parallel to the resistor the voltage across the pwm output hence all components' outputs is dropping and Arduino board's tiny L light fades in the circuit; whereas if I do the same with analog output 5v nothing happens. Is that because analog output has voltage regulator?

Comment: What is "analog output 5V"?

Comment: there is a 5V pin at Arduino AVR chip which is outputing constant 5V DC.

Comment: That's a supply line, not an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect a diode or capacitor between an output and ground, you are effectively either pulling that pin to one diode drop from ground or temporarily short-circuiting it to ground through the capacitor.

Either way, when the output then switches high, this drags the IC supply voltage down to this low value through the pull-up transistor in the output driver, subsequently causing a brownout condition if the supply cannot supply enough current to compensate.

Additionally, a diode reverse-biased between the 5V supply and ground will not conduct enough current to cause a brownout, while a forward-biased diode would conduct enough current to possibly burn itself out after a few seconds, depending on what the supply can handle in terms of current.

As for the capacitor across the supply, it will only be a short circuit until it charges up, then it will effectively be an open circuit. This differs from connecting it to a PWM output in that the PWM output switches between high and low. When high, the capacitor behaves exactly as it does when you initially put it across the supply, acting as a short circuit. *However*, the PWM output doesn't *stay* high. When it drops low, it *discharges* the capacitor, resetting it to look like a short circuit again when the output goes high.

Comment: "this drags the IC supply voltage down to this low value " So does that mean micro controller output voltages are not regulated?

Comment: @user16307: MCU output voltages are almost never regulated by the MCU; they pretty much only go through a single MOSFET before showing up on the output pin.

Comment: hmm i see.. but what if i use a voltage regulator just after the micro controller pin which outputs pwm with 5V  and feeds a capacitor(or diode) and resistance in parallel(just like in my circuit)? would i still see a voltage drop?

Comment: @user16307: That's a silly place to put a voltage regulator. Just don't deliberately do anything that could compromise the supply in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Ignacio's answer addresses the fundamentals of what is happening - but I wanted to try to clarify some conceptual errors in your question that may be hindering your understanding of the Arduino:

> **if I do the same with analog output 5v nothing happens**

The "5V" header socket supplies power from the 5 V regulator (MC33269D-5.0 on Arduino Uno [schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf))

It isn't supplying power from the AVR chip. It isn't an "output" of the AVR chip.

Power supplies can *NOT* be considered either *analog* or *digital* - they form their own category.

The 5V regulator can cope with a higher load than the ATmega outputs can. This probably accounts for the difference you see.

> **there is a 5V pin at Arduino AVR chip which is outputing constant 5V DC**

It is useful to distinguish between AVR controller pins and Arduino header sockets. Apart from the different numbering (package vs AVR vs Arduino), not all Arduino header positions are simple connections to AVR microcontroller pins. In particular, the GND, 5V and 3.3V header positions would continue to work if you removed the AVR microcontroller (you could test this in any Arduino that uses a socketed DIL ATmega chip).